# Determing non-equaling property values using Lambda in C#

Tags: c#, generics, properties, lambda, propertyinfo

At some point during my app, I am provided with a dictionary of data from a database query. I take that data and instance a object and invoke a `RestoreState()` method which takes the dictionary of data and applies the values to the corresponding properties within the new instance.

When the `RestoreState()` method is completed, i then pass the dictionary of values to the object into a property called `OriginalValues` like such:

```
myObject.EnableChangeTracking = true;
myObject.OrginalValues = dictionaryData;
```

Later on, the user makes some changes to the object via the UI and presses save. I then want to compare the existing state of the objects properties against the original state, so I can construct a update statement to send to SQL.

The problem (and question) is that my lambda expression to compare my current property value against the value in the dictionary does not work. The `OriginalValues` dictionary has 23 items, and the returned dictionary from my Lambda contains 14. In my unit test, I only change 2. Why am I getting back 12 additional values that have not changed?

My GetChanges method:

```
    public Dictionary<string, object> GetChanges()
    {
        if(!EnableChangeTracking || OrginalValues==null || !OrginalValues.Any())
            return new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // Only get properties that have changed.
        var changedProperties = 
            this
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.GetValue(this, null) != OrginalValues[p.Name])
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(this));

        return changedProperties;
    }
```

My `OriginalValues` dictionary contains:

- [0] {[AssetId, 1]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [1] {[SubFeatureId, 0]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [2] {[OrgNumber, 8555]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [3] {[LaneLocationId, ]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [4] {[StatusId, 1]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [5] {[AssetCode, 1]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [6] {[Note, There is nothing to see here.]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [7] {[DateActivated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [8] {[DateInactivated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [9] {[EnteredBy, JS]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [10]    {[DateEntered, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [11]    {[CreatedBy, JS]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [12]    {[UpdatedBy, JS]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [13]    {[DateCreated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [14]    {[DateUpdated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [15]    {[IsActive, True]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [16]    {[AssetAttributes, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FISDC.Models.AssetAttribute]]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [17]    {[AssetReasons, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FISDC.Models.AssetReason]]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [18]    {[AssetObjects, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FISDC.Models.AssetObject]]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [19]    {[SubFeature, ]}    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [20]    {[EnableChangeTracking, False]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [21]    {[IsValid, False]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [22]    {[OrginalValues, ]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair

and my Lambda expression returns:

- [0] {[AssetId, 1]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [1] {[SubFeatureId, 0]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [2] {[OrgNumber, 2222]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [3] {[StatusId, 1]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [4] {[DateActivated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [5] {[DateInactivated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [6] {[DateEntered, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [7] {[CreatedBy, SomeoneElse]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [8] {[DateCreated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [9] {[DateUpdated, 1/21/2014 9:12:08 AM]}   System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [10]    {[IsActive, True]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [11]    {[EnableChangeTracking, True]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [12]    {[IsValid, False]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair
- [13]    {[OrginalValues, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]} System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair

The only properties i changed in my unit test were OrgNumber and CreatedBy. Anyone have any ideas?

**Update**

The following is the code I use to update the properties, then invoke the `GetChanges()` method.

```
        myObject.OrgNumber = "2222";
        myObject.CreatedBy = "SomeoneElse";

        myDictionary = myObject.GetChanges();
```

**Update 2**

I'm curious if the issue is that my dictionary is `<string, object>` and I am comparing against both reference and non-reference types? So a int value is compared against a object and returned? I don't know.

**Update 3**

Working method thanks to @TTat

```
    public Dictionary<string,object> OrginalValues { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> GetChanges()
    {
        if(!EnableChangeTracking || OrginalValues==null || !OrginalValues.Any())
            return new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // Only get properties that have changed.
        var changedProperties = 
            this
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => !System.Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(IgnoreAttribute))
                         && !Equals(p.GetValue(this, null), OrginalValues[p.Name]))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(this));

        return changedProperties;
    }
```

Comment: In your GetChanges method, what is "this" referring to? Have you created an object that inherits from Dictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Comment: **this** refers to a instance of MyObject which inherits from Object. You pass the owning object of whom you want the property value of as a parameter in GetValue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your dictionary is `<string, object>`, `!=` will use a reference comparison.  Use the `Equals` method to check the value.  This uses the base Equals which will handle null results for you.

```
Where(p => !Equals(p.GetValue(this, null), OrginalValues[p.Name]))
```

Comment: I was aware of the != and equals issue but when I used p.GetValue(this, null).Equals(originalValues[p.Name]) I received a null reference exception. I was not aware of the base Equals, really slick thanks! I updated my OP to show the finished method.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Glad it worked.  Can you mark my answer as the solution then?

Comment: Another bug I found while testing this. It does not return any of the properties that have had their collections changed. I can understand it not detecting object changes within the collection, but shouldn't it detect that the size of the collection has changed at least?

Comment: I believe it will do a reference comparison.  So unless you create a new collection, it's still pointing to the same reference.  Something you should also pay attention to since you might be modifying the collection without knowing it.  Something you can do is check if the property is IEnumerable and use SequenceEqual.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it might do what I want.